# Brew update on macOS Catalina it fails with: “fatal: could not read Username for 'https://e.coding.net': terminal prompts disabled”

Tags: macos, homebrew

I am using macOS Catalina 10.15.2 and when I run `brew update` I get this issue:

```
$ brew update
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://e.coding.net': terminal prompts disabled
Error: Fetching /usr/local/Homebrew failed!
```

I have tried [the suggestion from this website](http://albertech.blogspot.com/2016/11/fix-git-error-could-not-read-username.html):

```
git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

But it still doesn’t work for me.

When I run:

```
brew doctor
```

I get this error:

```
Error: could not get runtime dependencies from /usr/local/opt/libmpc@0.8/.brew/libmpc@0.8.rb!

Warning: Some installed formulae are missing dependencies.
You should `brew install` the missing dependencies:
  brew install python@3.8 xz

Run `brew missing` for more details.
```

But when I run `brew missing` I get this error:

```
$ brew missing
Error: could not get runtime dependencies from /usr/local/opt/libmpc@0.8/.brew/libmpc@0.8.rb!
libxslt: xz python@3.8
```

Comment: Have you run `brew doctor` already, and fixed the issues it reports?

Comment: Well, did you run `brew install python@3.8 xz` as indicated by `brew doctor`?

Comment: Also, the suggestion you've implemented doesn't directly apply to Homebrew, not sure whether it had any effect (or even made matters worse)